# My Internet Service Provider Promised me 24 Mbps, but I have only 800k

Tags: internet-connection

My Internet Service Provider promise me 24 Mbps, but I'm lucky when I have 800 kbps. My router uses Ethernet and, as I read on the Ethernet cable, it allows up to 100 Mbps flowing. My router itself is a Thomson TG585 v7.

Were does the problem comes from? Can I increase the flow? Thank you. Cordially.

Comment: just a thought...800k could also be a single stream limit the ISP put in place.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like there are several issues going on here.

1. Your ISP reports speeds in terms of *bits* per second, while your browser reports in terms of *bytes*. That is, the ISP reports in Mbps, while the browser is reporting in KBps (case is important here) Because there is a factor of 8 difference between bits and bytes, your ISP actually provides 3MB/s download speeds.
2. The other end of the actual connection is important in terms of speed as well. If the servers on the other end cannot saturate your 24Mbps line (likely), then your line will be underutilized.
3. If you have a Cable ISP, you should know that often the ISP is reporting in terms of shared bandwidth, which means that your actual bandwidth would be dependent on the bandwidth use of other people residing in your neighborhood.
4. If you're on DSL, often advertised speeds are valid only near the phone distribution center, and your actual speeds will be lower if you are far from a distribution center.
5. Some bottlenecks are possibly between you/your ISP and the server you wish to reach and their ISP, which would be completely outside of your control.

Answer (score 2):

Go and check the small print carefully. Did they promise you 24Mbps or "up to" 24 Mbps?

Comment: In Finland the ISPs promise "always the maximum speed" ie. a bit every now and then. ;-)